# I'm getting an unexpected keyword error for "elsif"

Tags: ruby

```
def letter_case_count(string)
  char = new Hash
  char[:lower] = 0
  char[:upper] = 0
  char[:neither] = 0
  string.split("").each do |x| 
    if ('A'..'Z').include?(x) 
      char[:upper]++ 
    elsif ('a'..'z').include?(x) 
      char[:lower]++
    else
      char[:neither]++
    end
  end
end

puts letter_case_count('abCdef 123') == { lowercase: 5, uppercase: 1, neither: 4 }
puts letter_case_count('AbCd +Ef') == { lowercase: 3, uppercase: 3, neither: 2 }
puts letter_case_count('123') == { lowercase: 0, uppercase: 0, neither: 3 }
puts letter_case_count('') == { lowercase: 0, uppercase: 0, neither: 0 }
```

I get this error.

```
(repl):9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_elsif
    elsif ('a'..'z').include?(x) 
         ^
(repl):11: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else
(repl):13: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
(repl):20: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
...: 0, uppercase: 0, neither: 0 }
...    

                       ^
```

There are a bunch of unexpected keywords and unexpected end of inputs. Not sure why, I haven't programmed in Ruby in almost a yearn and I can't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby doesn't have `pre-increment` or `post-increment` operators. Use `+=1` and it should work.

```
def letter_case_count(string)
  char = {}
  char[:lower] = 0
  char[:upper] = 0
  char[:neither] = 0
  string.split('').each do |x| 
    if ('A'..'Z').include?(x) 
      char[:upper] += 1 
    elsif ('a'..'z').include?(x) 
      char[:lower] += 1
    else
      char[:neither] += 1
    end
  end
  char #returning the char is also important.
end
```

Using different keys for comparison will also return wrong results, it should be..

```
puts letter_case_count('abCdef 123') == { lower: 5, upper: 1, neither: 4 }
puts letter_case_count('AbCd +Ef') == { lower: 3, upper: 3, neither: 2 }
puts letter_case_count('123') == { lower: 0, upper: 0, neither: 3 }
puts letter_case_count('') == { lower: 0, upper: 0, neither: 0 }
```

**Better Approach:**

```
def letter_case_count(string)
  {
    lower: string.scan(/[a-z]/).count,
    upper: string.scan(/[A-Z]/).count,
    neither: string.scan(/[^a-z]/i).count
  }
end
```

Comment: "Shorter" is not necessarily "better". You're scanning the string once for each count.

Comment: isn't it better than generating two ranges `('A'..'Z')` and `('a'..'z')` then check for `include?` and that too for each character in the string.

Comment: You can use `count` like this too: `str.count("a-z")`, `str.count("A-Z")`, `str.count("1-9")` etc.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon `scan` is very fast because of its implementation and cannot be easily out-perfomed by a pure Ruby loop. But algorithm-wise, `scan` (or the underlying regular expression) has to compare each character in the string to a given set of characters, too. Furthermore, each call to `scan` creates an array containing the matches, although you are just interested in the number of matches.

Comment: It's been a while since I used Ruby, and I'm relearning it over again. I totally forgot the scan method, it's a really powerful tool. Thanks for taking time out of your day to help me!

Comment: My pleasure, please accept the answer if it helped.. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are bunch of syntax errors in your code.

```
def letter_case_count(string)
  char = Hash.new # not new Hash
  char[:lower] = 0
  char[:upper] = 0
  char[:neither] = 0
  string.split("").each do |x| 
    if ('A'..'Z').include?(x) 
      char[:upper]+=1 # var++ is not valid ruby code
    elsif ('a'..'z').include?(x) 
      char[:lower]+=1 #same here
    else
      char[:neither]+=1 # same here
    end
  end
end

puts letter_case_count('abCdef 123') == { lowercase: 5, uppercase: 1, neither: 4 }
puts letter_case_count('AbCd +Ef') == { lowercase: 3, uppercase: 3, neither: 2 }
puts letter_case_count('123') == { lowercase: 0, uppercase: 0, neither: 3 }
puts letter_case_count('') == { lowercase: 0, uppercase: 0, neither: 0 }
```

**UPDATE**

For that kind of tasks, use Ruby's minitest from stdlib.

All in one file example (all of them will fail)

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class String
  def letter_case_count
    char = Hash.new # not new Hash
    char[:lower] = 0
    char[:upper] = 0
    char[:neither] = 0
    self.split("").each do |x| 
      if ('A'..'Z').include?(x) 
        char[:upper]+=1 # var++ is not valid ruby code
      elsif ('a'..'z').include?(x) 
        char[:lower]+=1 #same here
      else
        char[:neither]+=1 # same here
      end
    end
    return char
  end
end

class TestFoo < MiniTest::Test

  def setup
    @w1, @w2, @w3, @w4 = ["abCdef 123", "AbCd +Ef", "123", ""].map {|e| String.new(e)}
  end

  def test_some
    assert_equal @w1.letter_case_count, { lowercase: 3, uppercase: 1, neither: 4 }
    end

  def test_some_other
    assert_equal @w2.letter_case_count, { lowercase: 3, uppercase: 3, neither: 2 }
  end
  def test_other
    assert_equal @w3.letter_case_count, { lowercase: 0, uppercase: 0, neither: 3 }
  end

  def test_definitely_other
    assert_equal @w4.letter_case_count, { lowercase: 0, uppercase: 0, neither: 0 }
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey man thanks. Unfortunately I totally forgot about these syntax rules! Thanks for helping me become a better programmer.